# how to import .cer file by web automatically

Tags: web-applications, import, certificate

I am trying to create a web page by any code and script to download and import a `.cer` file into trusted root of any client automatically.

For example: a java script that downloads the `.cer` file from a directory of my webserver and imports it into trusted root of client automatically.

Already, I have tried it by a VBScript code in local of client, but now I want to do this work by a web page, automatically, without notifying the browsing user.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a trusted root certificate is an EXTREMELY dangerous operation. There is absolutely no way to do this "without notifying the browsing user", nor should there be.

Comment: without notifying the browsing user, means that browsing user just accept a notify of implement java tools and my procces run in background service. the reason of this procces is protecting of my certification

Comment: Root certificates can have significant effects on the user's security. As such, the fact that you're installing one, and the details, should never be concealed from the user. I cannot imagine any legitimate reason why what you're describing should ever be necessary.

Comment: we use a encrypted connection between clients and server . hiding certification authority has been the best way to prevent any vulnerability

Comment: The root certificate can be obtained in about 30 seconds using the `openssl` command-line tool. It's public information -- hiding the fact that you're installing it has no purpose.

Comment: You are making less sense by the minute. If you are not using SSL, what **are** you using, and how is it supposed to work in a browser?

Comment: hi dears I search many page & library to find The best way to import a seft signed ca by javascript a find two way

Answer (score 0):

hi dears I search many page & library to find The best way to import a seft signed ca by javascript and find two way one:

```
` `
>    <html> 
>    <head> 
>        <title>Certificate install test2</title> 
>        </head> 
>        <body> 
>            <object id='CertEnroll' name='CertEnroll'></object> 
>            <object id='XEnroll' name='XEnroll'></object> 

>            <script language="javascript"> 

            var CERT_ENROLL_CLASSID = "clsid:884e2049-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09";

            function InstallCertChainCEnroll(pkcs7){
                CertEnroll.classid = CERT_ENROLL_CLASSID;
                var enrollObj = CertEnroll.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment");
                enrollObj.Initialize(1);
                for (var i=0;i<pkcs7.length;i++){
                    enrollObj.InstallResponse(4, pkcs7[i], 6, "");
                }
                return true;
            }

            document.write("<br>Installing certificate...");
            try{
                var pkcs7Chain = new Array();

                pkcs7Chain[0] =                                                     
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" +
                "MIIDUzCCAjugAwIBAgIIMPQ+41XDpAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzERMA8GA1UE" +
                "AwwIQWRtaW5DQTExFTATBgNVBAoMDEVKQkNBIFNhbXBsZTELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0Uw" +
                ....
                "QCU+xDRP4/o/HHR5T0MEYI+bmuWfF6hbGai6r4VlLmnQHb0Rs5mGDN3eHj0lyMhT" +
                "NiNSvPMvQviVxEsjwBjpYhe53cI4bxIVOpqW8GvxUot/Yakdy5xC" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

                InstallCertChainCEnroll(pkcs7Chain);
            } catch (ex){
                document.write("<br>" + ex);
                document.write("<br>" + ex.message);
            }            
>            </script> 
>        </body> 
>    </html> 

` `
```

and two:

```
` `
>    <html> 
>    <head> 
>        <title>Certificate install test2</title> 
>        </head> 
>        <body> 
>            <object id='CertEnroll' name='CertEnroll'></object> 
>            <object id='XEnroll' name='XEnroll'></object> 

>            <script language="javascript"> 

            var CERT_ENROLL_CLASSID = "clsid:884e2049-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09";

            function InstallCertChainCEnroll(pkcs7){
                CertEnroll.classid = CERT_ENROLL_CLASSID;
                var enrollObj = CertEnroll.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment");
                enrollObj.Initialize(1);
                for (var i=0;i<pkcs7.length;i++){
                    enrollObj.InstallResponse(4, pkcs7[i], 6, "");
                }
                return true;
            }

            document.write("<br>Installing certificate...");
            try{
                var pkcs7Chain = new Array();

                pkcs7Chain[0] =                                                     
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" +
                "MIIDUzCCAjugAwIBAgIIMPQ+41XDpAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzERMA8GA1UE" +
                "AwwIQWRtaW5DQTExFTATBgNVBAoMDEVKQkNBIFNhbXBsZTELMAkGA1UEBhMCU0Uw" +
                ....
                "QCU+xDRP4/o/HHR5T0MEYI+bmuWfF6hbGai6r4VlLmnQHb0Rs5mGDN3eHj0lyMhT" +
                "NiNSvPMvQviVxEsjwBjpYhe53cI4bxIVOpqW8GvxUot/Yakdy5xC" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

                InstallCertChainCEnroll(pkcs7Chain);
            } catch (ex){
                document.write("<br>" + ex);
                document.write("<br>" + ex.message);
            }            
>            </script> 
>        </body> 
>    </html> 

` `
```

but a problem is that usage of first code cuse this error:
Message: CertEnroll::CX509EnrollmentWebClassFactory::CreateObject: The operation was canceled by the user. 0x800704c7 (WIN32: 1223)
please see:
[microsoft msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/28/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments)

and when i use Second code
install my cer file in  Intermediate Certification Authorities area!!!!!!!!
What's happening is that this certificate in pkcs7Chain variable is a root certificate and IstallResponse method should install this guy in Trusted Root Certification Authorities, but is it installed in the Intermediate Certification Authorities area.!?
can i launch cmd by javascript in webpage and change(replace) ca from intermediate to trusted root?
(I can lauch cmd in ie)